# Items inside flexbox container are flowing out of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a portfolio page in which I am showing my 6 projects, 3 in a row using flexbox. The items inside are flowing out of the flexbox even though I have used flex-wrap. I am relatively new to this so I don't know what is happening.

[image]

The red border is my flexbox container and it contains six div elements. Inside each div element, there is one image and another div element which is like a caption. Each image is of a different size

HTML Code:

```
<section id="work">
    <h1><u>These are some of my projects</u></h1>
    <div id="work-container">
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">Tribute Page</div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">Random Quote Machine</div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">JavaScript Calculator</div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">Map Data Across the Globe</div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">Wikipedia Viewer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-block">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png" alt="">
            <div id="project-title">Tic Tac Toe Game</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="view-more"></button>
</section>
```

CSS Used:

```
#work-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;

}

.work-block{
    width: 28%;
    margin: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .work-block{
        width: 45%;
    }
}

#work-container img{
    height: calc(100% );
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    flex:none;
}
```

There is one particular line which is enabling equal height for all images `height: calc(100% );`. I don't know how it works, I took it from the internet. It was used to have the equal height for each image.

Also, the bottom and the top margin between blocks is not working.

I want some help in wrapping content inside container properly and understanding how `height: calc(100% );` works.

Complete Code: https://codepen.io/tushar_432/pen/poyxmyZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the image `height:100%`, this will make the image take all the space pushing the text outside thus the overflow. Use flexbox to make it fill all the space minuse the text space:

```css
#work-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.work-block {
  width: 28%;
  margin: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .work-block {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
.work-block {
  display:flex; /* here */
  flex-direction:column; /* here */
}
.work-block img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 1; /* here */
}
```

```html
<section id="work">
  <h1><u>These are some of my projects</u></h1>
  <div id="work-container">
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">Tribute Page</div>
    </div>
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">Random Quote Machine</div>
    </div>
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">JavaScript Calculator</div>
    </div>
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">Map Data Across the Globe</div>
    </div>
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">Wikipedia Viewer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="work-block">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png" alt="">
      <div id="project-title">Tic Tac Toe Game</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it worked. Can you please explain how adding .workblock{display:flex} helped? What was happening before and now?

Comment: @TusharAgrawal it's not only the flex property. I made the container flexbox and used a column direction to be able to use flex:1 which will make the element take all the free space instead of taking all the block space when you were using height:100%;

Comment: @TusharAgrawal you should check flexbox. It will help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your caption is overflowing, you can add

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to your `.work-block`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Catamaran:wght@400;600&family=Raleway:ital@1&display=swap');

*,*::before,*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top:0;
}

body{
    background-color: bisque;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#header{
    position: sticky;
    top:0px;
    margin:0;
}
#navbar{
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color:#12343b;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding:18px;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: 450;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.nav-block:hover{
    color:#e1b382;
}
.nav-block{
    padding:0 20px;
}

#about h1{
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #fefefe;
}

#about h3{
    font-size:24px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #e1b382;
}

#about{
    text-align: center;
    padding:250px;
    background-color:#2d545e;
    color:white;
}

#work{
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color: #e1b382;

}

#work h1{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #12343b;
    
}

#work-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;

}

.work-block{
    width: 28%;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .work-block{
        width: 45%;
    }
}

#work-container img{
    height: calc(100% );
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    flex:none;
} 

#contact{
    padding:150px;
    background-color: #2d545e;
}

#contact-container{
    display: flex;
}

#footer{
    padding:40px;
    background-color:#2d545e;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"> 
<header id="header">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="nav-block">About</div>
            <div class="nav-block">Work</div>
            <div class="nav-block">Contact</div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="about">
        <h1>Hey I am Tushar</h1><br>
        <h3>a computers <br>and technology enthusiast</h3>
    </section>

    <section id="work">
        <h1><u>These are some of my projects</u></h1>
        <div id="work-container">
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">Tribute Page</div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">Random Quote Machine</div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">JavaScript Calculator</div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">Map Data Across the Globe</div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">Wikipedia Viewer</div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-block">
                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png" alt="">
                <div id="project-title">Tic Tac Toe Game</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="view-more"></button>
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
        <h1>Let's Work Together</h1>
        <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
        <div id="contact-container">
            <div class="contact-block">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-block">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i><span>Github</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-block">
                <i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i><span>Twitter</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-block">
                <i class="fas fa-at"></i><span>Send a mail</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-block">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i><span>Call me</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
        <span>**This is just a fake portfolio. All the projects and contact details given are not real.</span>
        <span>© Created for freeCodeCamp </span>
    </footer>
```